# How do I include all zero-argument public instance methods in to_json automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, metaprogramming

I have the following:

```
class Foo

  def bar
    "foobar"
  end

  def baz
    "foobaz"
  end

  def qux(arg)
    ...
  end

end
```

How do I override `as_json` so that it includes keys and values for the methods `bar` and `baz`, but not `qux`, without explicitly specifying them?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
def get_public_methods
   array = self.public_methods(false).delete_if {|meth| Foo.instance_method(meth).arity > 0}.map{|meth| [meth, self.send(meth)]}

   Hash[*array.flatten]
end
```

which will return `{:bar=>"foobar", :baz=>"foobaz"}`

Then, call `get_public_methods` in your `as_json` overload.